# DateTime - Specifying Kind Which Form Makes Most Sense

Tags: c#, datetime

I've just been reviewing some code and in the process I've discovered a problem which I'm in the process of fixing.  One of the issues involved a blanket date conversion routine on our data context.

Anyway, during investigation I came across some code like this:

```
    case DateTimeKind.Unspecified:
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind(dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Looking through some other code I found someone else doing this:

```
if (value.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified) {
    return new DateTime(value.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
}
```

I can't help feeling like the first is "best". I know they both essentially do the same thing - generate a new `DateTime` object.  But the first seems more readable in terms of the original intent - take this date, give me the same one back but with Utc specified.

It feels more immediately readable.  I know this is possibly edging towards an opinion based thing but readability is really important.

Comment: Seems like you have answered your own question. Can't say I disagree however.

Comment: Luckily from reviewing the SVN logs I wrote the top one! :)  Go me!

Comment: It's entirely up to you. [`SpecifyKind()` calls the second example internally anyway.](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#713)

Comment: Yes I know, I stated that in the question.  The point was really about readability.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no one objective answer. I would take the first approach - looks cleaner to me. However, I could also argue that using a constructor is what people are more used to. Not everyone knows SpecifyKind exists.

I also have to say that both of these methods are not that bad. Any developer with at least few months of experience will understand both approaches just fine.

Answer (score 0):

They are identical.  If you look at [the implementation of `DateTime.SpecifyKind`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#713), you will find:

```
public static DateTime SpecifyKind(DateTime value, DateTimeKind kind) {
    return new DateTime(value.InternalTicks, kind);
}
```

(and `.Ticks` resolves to `.InternalTicks`)

As far as readability, I would go with `SpecifyKind`.  Ticks are more of an internal implementation detail.  You really shouldn't have to do much with them to be proficient with `DateTime`.

Just be careful with *where* you use this code.  If all dates are in UTC, then you're fine.  But if you are converting between other time zones, `Unspecified` may actually be appropriate.